# Colorcode the indents level / visual indication in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I am using Spyder for some Numpy work currently and python's indentation mechaninc is confusing me a little. It would be really helpful if I could have some color coding for each indentation level or some dotted lines (like in notepad++). Is there a way to turn such a feature on, or any plugins I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This functionality is available since Spyder **2.3.3** and you can activate it under the menu entry

```
Source > Show blank spaces
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for listening to feedback. I wish I could help you in this regard (Il still give it a shot :) )

But above all let me take a momet to express my sincerest thanks for developing possibly the best IDE for python. - @carlos

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. They are really important to us :)

Comment: I looked for that discussion a lot in the past. Has that already happened @CarlosCordoba ?

Answer (score 0):

This Spyder looks wery nice IDE, but I'd prefer real gray dashed indent lines.

I saw these were already done for a dev version, are there some issues why not to add this feature also to the offical version?