# Indication of indentation in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Is there a way to indicate indentation level in Spyder?

This question from 2013: [Colorcode the indents level / visual indication in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539915/colorcode-the-indents-level-visual-indication-in-spyder) also asks this.  The only answer (by @CarlosCordoba) states that there was no such option at the time, but that it might be included in a later release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have a visual aid of the indentation level in Spyder, you need to go to the menu

`Source > Show blank spaces`